# Can I post a similar answer on two different questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

Yesterday the question  [Maximum/Minimum of all subarrays/ Windows of size k (Must Read the Accepted Answer, New Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233686/) was asked. It turned out to be a duplicate of [Finding maximum for every window of size k in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031939/). I'm a new Stack Overflow user, so I didn't know that and answered it with an entirely new algorithm that isn't on Stack Overflow. I now realize that question has been repeated two other times. My method is better than the others, but I didn't get much rep for the answer since it's on a duplicate. Can I repeat this answer on the other posts so it gets more attention?

Comment: `but i think i didn't get quite rep for that answer like i should`. Heh. Of course you would think that, it is _your_ answer, after all ;)

Comment: the method i described was too easy to code..you are a programmer. you can judge yourself sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer brings something *different* to the duplicate, that is, it is a better answer than the *existing* ones, by all means post it on the duplicate.

However, make sure you are answering the duplicate question - having a question marked as a duplicate doesn't always mean that it is *exactly* the same. You still need to make sure the answer is a good one for the duplicate.

This does not mean you should look for all duplicates and post your answer unchanged - the existing answers, what your answer brings to a question and whether it is an appropriate answer for it should all be taken into consideration when deciding whether to post it on a different question.